# Why does a linked list with a double pointer cause an error?

Tags: c, linked-list, double-pointer

I'm asking you a question because the assignment I was doing didn't work out.
The structure is a common link list, declaring the head pointer in the main and passing the address value of the head pointer as a parameter to the function.
The global variable top is used to determine where the current data is located.

The code currently below will detect only errors when executed.

Structure:

```
struct ListNode{
    int data;
    struct ListNode* link;
};
int top = 0;
```

code:

```
void DisplayList(ListNode** head){
    if(*head == NULL){
        printf("List = Empty\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("List = ");
        for(;(*head) != NULL; *head = (*head)->link){
            printf("%d ",(*head)->data);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void AddList(ListNode** head){
    ListNode* temp = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    int num;
    printf("Data register) ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    temp->data = num;
    temp->link = NULL;
    top++;

    if(*head == NULL){  
        *head = temp;
    }
    else{
        for(;(*head)->link != NULL; *head = (*head)->link){}    
        (*head)->link = temp;
    }
    DisplayList(head);
}
```

### the expected result:

Data register) 10
List = 10

Data register) 20
List = 10 20

Data register) 30
List = 10 20 30

---

Comment: What do you mean by the assignment we were working on is not working out? We're not working on any assignment.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've revised it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify `*head` in the loops. You need to use a local variable to step through the list, otherwise you're changing the caller's variable to point to the end of the list.

```
void DisplayList(ListNode** head){
    if(*head == NULL){
        printf("List = Empty\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("List = ");
        for(ListNode *step = *head;step != NULL; step = step->link){
            printf("%d ",step->data);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void AddList(ListNode** head){
    ListNode* temp = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    int num;
    printf("Data register) ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    temp->data = num;
    temp->link = NULL;
    top++;

    if(*head == NULL){  
        *head = temp;
    }
    else{
        ListNode *step = *head;
        for(;step->link != NULL; step = step->link){}    
        step->link = temp;
    }
    DisplayList(head);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in how you traverse the list:

```
for(; (*head)->link != NULL; *head = (*head)->link) {}
```

At the beginning, `*head` is the head of the list from the calling function. By assigning to it, you overwrite it continuously, until it becomes null.

Instead, you should assign to `head`: It holds the address of the head node in the calling function at first and the address of the `link` pointer of the previous node in subsequent iterations:

```
for(; (*head)->link != NULL; head = &(*head)->link) {}
```

After this loop, `head` holds the address of the pointer where the new node should be stored. Assign the new node to that pointer directly:

```
*head = temp;
```

This will update the head pointer of the calling function when the list was empty and the `link` member of the previous node otherwise. You don't have to treat the case where the list is empty specially.

The insertion function might now look like this:

```
void AddList(ListNode** head, int num)
{
    ListNode* temp = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    temp->data = num;
    temp->link = NULL;

    while (*head) head = &(*head)->link);
    *head = temp;
}
```

(In my opinion, reading the input and printing the list shoudl not be part of te insertion function.)

---

Regarding your printing function: Seeing a function like that:

```
void DisplayList(ListNode** head)
```

raises a red flag: Passing a pointer to node pointer signals that you want to modify the list (and you inadvertently do that), but printing the list only inspects it. Change the signature to

```
void DisplayList(const ListNode* head)
```

then use `head` instead of `(*head)` in the function. (Rule of thumb: If you never use `*head = ...` somewhere in the list, you don't need a pointer to node pointer.)

Comment: I find your answer confusing, using `head` as a local variable. It also doesn't handle the empty list as the new element must be put in `*head`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I does handle insertion to an empty list, but the assignment must be `*head = temp`, which my answer doesn't explian properly.